# В bootstrap в ссылках добавлять атрибут target=_blank только для больших устройств

Tags: html, bootstrap

Есть сайт-каталог сделанный на bootstrap. В каталоге каждая ссылка ведет на свою страницу.В каждой ссылке установлен   атрибут target=_blank  чтобы каждая страничка открывалась в новой вкладке. Однако на сотовых телефонах нужно чтобы этого атрибута не было так как в мобильных браузерах в этом случае не активна стрелка возврата на предыдущую страницу.

Вариант рисовать две ссылки для маленьких экранов и больших экранов не подойдет так как это не очень хорошо скажется для seo как я понимаю.

Comment: Определяем что клиент сидит с мобильного телефона, убираем атрибут target.
$('div').removeAttr('targer')

Comment: а я бы порекомендовал убрать `target="_blank"` из всех внутренних ссылок сайта, потому что уже давно общепринято в разработке рунета, что все внутренние ссылки открываются в этом же окне, если конечно вы не делаете сайт для Китая, там вроде концепция другая

Comment: тоже начал склоняться к этому варианту, а где про это написано?

Comment: @MasterAlex поэтому яндекс как знамя рунета, все ссылки открывает в новом окне

Comment: @heff Как вам мой скрипт? Помог?

Comment: @L.Vadim, вы про малопопулярный браузер или про сайт? Полазил по всем сервисам сайта Яндекс и ни одной новой вкладки не открылось, всё в одной.

Comment: @MasterAlex Ну как же, поиск яндекс

Comment: @L.Vadim, результаты поиска это уже не внутренние страницы яндекса, а внешние ресурсы, и вполне логично что другие сайты открываются в новой вкладке, это кстати тоже общепринято

Comment: @MasterAlex Если говорить по делу, новое окно это плохой тон. Например гугл поиск не позволяет себе новых окон не в каком сервисе.

Comment: @L.Vadim, очень странно, потому что у меня результаты поиска на гугле в браузере гугл хром тоже открываются исключительно в новом окне :)

Comment: @MasterAlex  Проверил, только в google.ru, проверьте другие страны

Answer (score 1):

Проверяем ширину окна, если равно 400 или ширина другая, какая вам нужна, то меняем аттрибут. Всем ссылкам на сайте.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($(window).width() == 400)
  {
      $('body').find('a').each(function() {
      $(this).attr('target',"_self");
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: честно говоря не пробовал, сделал чтобы внутренние ссылки открывались в новом окне.

Comment: ну это полный ответ на ваш вопрос, попробуйте

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).